# Generate objects from string

Tags: python, string, variables, object

I have a list of strings each representing books and some of their properties, e.g.

```
# each book followed by the price and the name of the genre
book_names = ['love 3 romance',
              'rose 6 drama',
              'flower 7 nice_story']
```

I want to somehow create a new object for each of these books and make the other parts of the string description attributes thereof.

This is what I've tried (Obviously, it doesn't work):

```
class Book_Class():
  price=0
  genre=''
  book_content=[]

for i in book_names:
  name=i.split()[0]
  name=Book_Class()
  name.price=i.split()[1]
  name.genre=i.split()[2]
```

Maybe there is a simple way to achieve what I'm after (please tell me, as I'm fairly new to programming...).

Comment: No, you don't. Use a dict. (Also, that's not the syntax for defining a class, not that this is particularly relevant to your question)

Comment: Perhaps you meant `genre` instead of `gender`?

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways:

1. Use a dictionary instead, it is more than sufficient in many cases:

   ```
   keys = ['name', 'price', 'gender']
   book = { k: v for k, v in zip(keys, i.split()) }
   ```
2. Give your `Book` class a meaningful `__init__` initializer:

   ```
   class Book(object):
       name = ''
       price = 0
       gender = None

       def __init__(self, name, price, gender):
           self.name = name
           self.price = price
           self.gender = gender
   ```

   and pass your parsed values into that:

   ```
   Book(*i.split())
   ```
3. As a last resort, you can use [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr) to set arbitrary attributes on an existing object:

   ```
   book = Book()
   for attr, value in zip(keys, i.split()):
       setattr(book, attr, value)
   ```

Comment: Note that `book = {k:v for k,v in zip(keys,i.split())}` only works for python 2.7 or newer (as I'm sure Martijn is well aware).  If you want compatability with older versions: `dict((k,v) for k,v in zip(keys,i.split()))` is equivalent -- or just `dict(zip(keys,i.split()))`.

Comment: i'm not yet too competent to judge the readability and efficiency of code.So i would ask - using `globals()` looks shorter, would you say that your way is better?

Comment: But your code doesn't allow me to make a call like `print love.price`

Comment: @MihkelL.: you don't want the ability to do that. You may think you do, but you don't. Why would you be trying to use a hardcoded variable "love" in your code if you don't ever hardcode a definition for the variable? Variable-named variables are *always* a sign of a bad design.

Comment: Because i want to be able to ask, if an object with the "love" is already existent, then i want to add to the last value of love.price :). But  bad design could be the case, and probably is will look into it! :)

Comment: @MihkelL.: Really, store your objects in a dictionary; `books` for example. Then use `'love' in books` to see if it already has been defined. Use `books['love'].price` to retrieve an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do the same task is by using named tuple.

```
book_names = ['love 3 romance',
              'rose 6 drama',
              'flower 7 nice_story']

from collections import namedtuple
book = namedtuple("Book", "name price genre")

# convert book_names to books
[book(*b.split()) for b in book_names]

Output: [Book(name='love', price='3', genre='romance'),
         Book(name='rose', price='6', genre='drama'),
         Book(name='flower', price='7', genre='nice_story')]
```

Then you can access the properties as expected

```
book1 = [book(*b.split()) for b in book_names][0]
print book1.name, book1.price, book1.genre
Output: ('love', '3', 'romance')
```

If you want to use first param as variable name you can do:

```
book = namedtuple("Book", "price genre")
for b in book_names:
    globals()[b.split()[0]] = book(*b.split()[-2:])

# now you can access your books:
love.price
```

Comment: actually i want to be able to call the price and genre with the book name. like love.price love.genre

Answer (score 0):

An answer that was given by Ashwini Chaudhary, is using globals()

```
# each book followed by the price and the name of the genre
book_names = ['love 3 romance',
              'rose 6 drama',
              'flower 7 nice_story']
class Book_Class():
  price=0
  genre=''
  book_content=[]
for i in book_names:
  nnn='name'
  globals()[nnn]=i.split()[0]
  name=Book_Class()
  name.price=i.split()[1]
  name.gender=i.split()[2]
```